# How to access the version of Beamer and tikz inside of LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

How would I typeset inside of a document the version of the beamer and of the tikz package. Such as in

```
This document was typeset with beamer in version \beamerversion and tikz in version \tikzversion
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beamer defines the macro `\beamerugversion`, which stores the current version number, in its documentation. You can e.g. use the `readarray` package to access it (replace the path to wherever the documentation is installed on your system):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{readarray}
\readrecordarray{/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/doc/latex/beamer/beameruserguide.tex}\data
\data[16]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

This document was typeset with beamer in version \beamerugversion\ and tikz in version \pgfversion

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\listfiles%-----------------log file will now display all version data

\begin{document}
 I am using verion number \pgfversion%-----------------will print tikz pgf version
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi there, please don't make negative votes without explanation!

Comment: It seems this answers only the part about the `tikz` version. Maybe you could add some description and use the `beamer` class as wished in the question.

Comment: With `\listfiles` the version of the packages are listed in the log file. See the file with extension `log` produced when you compile the tex file. The beamer version will be there.

Comment: This answer was more useful than the previous one. `\listfiles` with `beamer` as `\documentclass` spells out the version in the `.log` file. Very useful tool indeed. Is there any single place where we can learn such things?